# Is there an alternative to the archived rdrop2 package

Tags: r, dropbox, rdrop2

The package `rdrop2` was archived on 31/07/20 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rdrop2/index.html

Is anyone aware of a good alternative to this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recently updated version of rdrop2 on Github: https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2. You can install it using `devtools::install_github`.